# This is error message "Could not save; currently locked by another user."

Tags: vb.net

Can you help you find to any solution? Because it's output error message as "Could not save; currently locked by another user."

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

    If txtPassword.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtUsername.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtSurName.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtGivenName.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtMobile.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtAddress.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")
    ElseIf txtIC.Text.ToString() = "" Then
        MsgBox("do not empty")

    Else
        Dim gender As String

        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then

            gender = "Male"
        Else
            gender = "Female"

        End If

        Dim fsr As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fsr)
        Dim imgbuffer(fsr.Length) As Byte
        br.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsr.Length)
        fsr.Close()

        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =..\VisitorPass.accdb")

            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "Update HouseOwner set [Password]='" & txtPassword.Text & "',AccountName='" & txtUsername.Text & "',Houseowner_Surname='" & txtSurName.Text & "',Houseowner_GivenName='" & txtGivenName.Text & "',[IC]='" & txtIC.Text & "',[Mobile_No]='" & txtMobile.Text & "',Houseowner_address='" & txtAddress.Text & "',Gender='" & gender & "',[Photo]= @imgfile where [ID]=" & lblID.Text & ""
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgfile", imgbuffer)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Profile is updated")
                con.Close()


            End Using
        End Using

        Me.Close()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the database opened in access and the table HouseOwner is opened in design view?

Comment: i have no open the database when i using my program.

Comment: And in what line do you receive the error message?

Comment: Could not save; currently locked by another user.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()